# ER diagram relationship for user admin

Tags: database, relationship, entity-relationship

I am designing a Database management project of gym management. There are 2 users, one is the clerk who can add,remove and edit all trainers, centers and members and the second user is the member who can  only see and edit certain attributes related to him. Member ,center and trainers are 3 entities in the ER diagram so the question should I introduce entity for clerk and if so should it have a relationship with any of the three entities described above?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't split up the two Entities based on the Fact that they have different permissions in your system. 
I recommend you focus on the concepts behind the entities:

- First, if all Attributes are equal I would start considering building 1 Entity out of the two. Once you end up with multiple columns that are mainly null it might have been a mistake to "merge" two entities.
- In addition to that you should check if there is a central name that you can give your merged entity. For example if you have the two Entities: Manager, Employee and you want to merge them I would maybe just call it User and check if the Properties still make sense in that context.
- Last but not least you should think about how the Entities are used later in the development. If you need two Joins instead of one once you split up your Entities that could be an argument for merging them. Maybe later in the development your 'clark' Entity will be extended by a few columns, this way you might end up with null columns again.

I think a general answer is not suitable since the Domain is unclear. Just collect arguments for and against merging the entities and compare those.

Comment: Member and clerk have different attributes and difference is more than three. Since it is gym system it has more attributes like gender and all. Whereas the clerk has only name and id. The clerk can add new instances of entity member, trainer and location. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Ok so since you have different attributes I would guess that you should split them up in two Entities. Since they are basically not the same.

Comment: And relate them to all three other entities or only one will do?

Comment: Well there is no general Answer once again. If there is a real world relation between them, it might make sense. Maybe a basic example can help you. If you have a school class and Students then a relation is useful. The relation (foreign key constraint) ensures that each student has a class at any given time.
Just a guess: 
- Your clark Entity "owns" a center, so there should be a relation between them.
- The clark creates relations between trainers / members and the center -> so there should be a relation between trainer and center as well as member and center.